# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies on Windows 8 IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I got this problem when deploying on my localhost IIS. I haven't experience error when building the system and publish correctly. But when you browse it on localhost suddenly got error. I already do some research and suggestion on google but nothing works for me. Can someone help me on this:

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web' could not be loaded.

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Stack Trace:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +210
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +17
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerHelper.GetAssembly(String name) +88
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.IsScriptCombinable(ScriptEntry scriptEntry, Boolean enableCdn) +48
   AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnResolveScriptReference(ScriptReferenceEventArgs e) +266
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScripts() +349
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPagePreRenderComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +281
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4628
```

Comment: Are you using IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: I'm using IIS on windows 8.

Comment: Try running these two commands from the Command Prompt (elevated mode):

1 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
2 iisreset

Comment: @user1852837 Check if .Net framework 4.0 is installed.

Comment: .NET 4.5 is installed

Comment: And you have run the aspnet_regiis -i ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to register .net Freamework 4.0 for IIS for the above issue. Here are the steps..

- Open Command prompt as Administrator
- Navigate to "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory in command prompt [use the command cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319]
- Register .net FrameWork for IIS [use command  aspnet_regiis.exe -i]
- Restart IIS [use command  iisreset].
- Done.

**OR THIS**

In VS2010, right click the project in the Solution Explorer and select 'Add Deployable Dependencies'. Then check the MVC related check boxes in the following dialog.

This creates a '_bin_deployableAssemblies' folder in the project which contains all the .dll files mentioned in other answers. I believe these get copied to the bin folder when creating a deployment package.

**or try this:**
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

1. ask your self have you register asp.net with IIS using A[SP.NET IIS Registration Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)
2. ask your self have you set the app-pool to be of [updated asp.net version](http://i2.asp.net/media/3066894/Windows-Live-Writer_9a5cc04aa344_9D47_Inetmgr_selecting_Basic_Settings_for_app_pool_4.png?cdn_id=2015-07-02-001).
3. set identity for [app pool](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).